# How to stack multiple violin plots inside a 3d plot in python

Tags: python, 3d, 2d, violin-plot

Hello and thank you in advance for any ideas. I have generated a large number (~126) of violin plots from a time-series dataset. I have three different classes that I'm interested in assessing through 8 different sensors. I would like to take the 3 classes of violin plots and stack them inside a 3d plot 8 times. Here is a sample of the kind of violin plots I'm working with, generated from the seaborn package in python:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mdoja.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7asZ.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLgTf.png)

Sample code for generating the violin plot is:

```
Classes:
p1 = dfp1.iloc[:,8]
p2 = dfp2.iloc[:,8]
p3 = dfp3.iloc[:,8]

Coil 2
fig, ax = pyplot.subplots(figsize=(17,7), dpi=200)
g = sns.violinplot(ax = ax, data = [p1,p2,p3])
plt.title("T: Coil 2 R: Coil 3")
g.set_xticklabels(['P1', 'P2', 'P3'])
g.set_xlabel("Class") 
g.set_ylabel("Amplitude (V) x$10^4$")
g.set_ylim([-3.8, 3.8])
```

Comment: Please clarify: would you like the violin curves "standing" parallel to one another in a 3d plot? if so what would be your third axis?

Comment: Yes, is it possible to have a set of 3 violin plots in parallel with 8 total iterations? It would be perfect if a set of 3 violin plots could run along the x and z axis with each different iteration running along the y axis. So in a way, the 3d plot would be acting like a 3d subplot if that makes sense.